# How can i delete the record from both table at a time

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
create table emp_data(
      emp_code number primary key, 
      emp_name varchar2(25)not null,
      dept_name varchar2(25),
      manager_name varchar2(25));

create table emp_asi(
      asi_no number primary key, 
      asi_desc varchar2(50), 
      asi_status varchar2(20), 
      created_by varchar2(20));

create table emp_rel(
      asi_no number, 
      asi_emp number,
      asi_date date,
      comp_date date, 
constraint fk_asi_no foreign key(asi_no)
references emp_asi(asi_no), 
constraint fk_asi_emp foreign key(asi_emp) references emp_data(emp_code));
```

**Emp**

```
table record: emp_code  emp_name    dept_name   manager_name
              1001      ABC         MNOP        S
```

**Asi**

```
table record: asi_no    asi_desc    asi_status    created_by
              101       sdslk       sdfg           O
```

**Emp_asi**

```
table record: asi_no    emp_code 
              101       1001
```

how to delete 1001 record from **emp** table and **emp_asi** in a single query..

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* possible.

What you can do, anyway is to delete them in a single `transacrtion`.

Read the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a single query but if you have the foreign key defined with ON DELETE CASCADE, you do not need to bother it for the table where it is a primary key.
Caveat: Do read up the side effects of CASCADE before implementing that.